# Only last line of output being retrieved from stdout (contextlib, sys.stdout, and capture magic)

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, stdout, stringio

I'm trying to capture terminal output to store it elsewhere. Specifically, I'm trying to retrieve the training loss from `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression`. This is unfortunately not stored anywhere, but is printed when `verbose=1`.

I am trying to use `contextlib.redirect_stdout` to do this. However, it only captures the last line of output.

Full terminal output without redirection:

```
[Parallel(n_jobs=8)]: Using backend ThreadingBackend with 8 concurrent workers.
Epoch 1, change: 1.00000000
Epoch 2, change: 0.22057155
Epoch 3, change: 0.12789722
Epoch 4, change: 0.06779011
Epoch 5, change: 0.04539726
Epoch 6, change: 0.03062415
Epoch 7, change: 0.02026218
Epoch 8, change: 0.01470303
Epoch 9, change: 0.00691171
Epoch 10, change: 0.00415176
Epoch 11, change: 0.00230851
Epoch 12, change: 0.00145497
Epoch 13, change: 0.00110029
convergence after 14 epochs took 1 seconds
[Parallel(n_jobs=8)]: Done   1 out of   1 | elapsed:    0.5s finished
```

`redirect_stdout` outputs only the following line:

```
convergence after 14 epochs took 1 seconds
```

Code sample:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
import io            

model = LogisticRegression(
                    random_state=42,
                    C=.001,
                    penalty='l1',
                    max_iter=1000,
                    solver='saga',
                    verbose=1))

with redirect_stdout(io.StringIO()) as f:
   model.fit(X_train, y_train)
s = f.getvalue()
print(s)
```

I've had the same results when using `sys.stdout` directly or in a Jupyter notebook using `%%capture`.

Does anyone know what is causing this or how to extract the full output?
Thanks!

Comment: The "Epoch" messages seem likely to be printed by native code, for which `redirect_stdout` has no control over...

Comment: This could be it -- I thought it might just be getting overwritten, but I tried outputting directly to a file and it successfully saves text before and after the actual epochs.

Comment: My guess would be that this is due to the use of multiprocessing. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout): _"... is not suitable for use in library code and most **threaded applications**. It also has **no effect on the output of subprocesses**."_

Comment: I suspect it is what Timus says. If it were what AKX says, you'd use [wurlitzer](https://github.com/minrk/wurlitzer). I don't think it will help here in this case, but for anyone encountering a case like AKX seems to be referencing, i.e., actual C-level out, see especially under "Forward C-level stdout/stderr to Python sys.stdout/stderr, which may already be forwarded somewhere by the environment, e.g. IPython" on [the wurlitzer documentation page under 'Usage'](https://github.com/minrk/wurlitzer#usage).

Comment: @Timus I'm about 97.6% sure this doesn't spawn subprocesses.

Comment: @AKX That's a rather specific confidence level :)) It was just a guess, since I ran into a similiar problem a while ago when using multiple processes.